# Oracle Developers guide 10g is not connecting to sever

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs

I have installed oracle developers guide 10g in my windows 10, it installed successfully.

While connecting to Oracle EBS host data base it give an error

Entered detail on connection screen -

User -  myuser

Pass -  mypass

Connect String -  myuser@SID

Error -

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Cause

The service name specified is not defined correctly in the
TNSNAMES.ORA file.
I check my TNSNAMES.ORA file at my database host machine

I found entry TNSNAMES.ORA -

```
SID =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = SID)
    )
  )
```

where and what changes i need do in settings file to connect it properly.

Note - host machine OS Linux

Note -

**tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora files are present at two places**

**1- C:\DevSuiteHome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN - Path created after installing oracle developer guide 10g**

**2- E:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN - previous oracle installation path**

is there any catch in this file locations ?

Comment: Did you tried to connect with SQLPlus?

Comment: Yes it is connecting properly.

Comment: The `tnsnames.ora` has to be on the *client* machine, i.e. on your Windows PC. I'm not sure what "oracle developers guide" means, but the file needs to be somewhere that client application is expecting it to be.

Comment: I think this question will be more suitable for [Database Administrators Site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @AlexPooleOracle developers guide is designing tool used for oracle

Comment: Type "Path" in command windows and get the path for installed oracle home directory and check whether your tnsname.ora files available in given client path.

Comment: yes it has oracle home path

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused with the question, but I will try to answer as far as I can understand:

You have 2 tnsnames.ora, one in the db server and another in client, you need to look at the tnsnames.ora in the client machine (where sql developer is installed), check if the **SERVICE_NAME** is pointing to the right SSID of the Oracle Server, then check if **HOST** is pointing to the right machine name / IP (I personally like to use IP better).

then on the command prompt, try tnsping (assuming you have one):

Using the tnsnames.ora you posted, it will be something like:

```
C:\>tnsping.exe SID
```

Let me know how it goes

**UPDATE:**

Here's an example of how to do it:

`Oracle Server IP: 192.168.1.220 with SID: ORCL`

`My Computer IP: 192.168.1.200`

Content of tnsnames.ora in My Computer:

> Blockquote
>
> BLAHSERVER=
>     (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS_LIST =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.220)(PORT = 1521))
>       )
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)
>       )
>     )

Then you should be able to do the following:

```
C:\> tnsping.exe BLAHSERVER
C:\> sqlplus username/password@BLAHSERVER
```

Comment: after tnsping on both my machine and other host machine i got following result -

C:\Users\mymachine>tnsping mymachine
Used parameter files:
C:\DevSuiteHome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=my_machine_name))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=my_ip)(PORT=1521)))
OK (20 msec)
C:\Users\mymachine>tnsping IP.32.88
Used parameter files:
C:\DevSuiteHome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=192.168.32.88))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=IP.32.88)(PORT=1521)))
OK (70 msec)

Comment: sounds ok, if your sqlplus username@IP.32.88 is ok too, then the sql developer should be good to go, unless the sql developer did not load the tnsnames.ora correctly

Comment: After executing command - 
C:\Users\afgan>sqlplus APPS@IP.32.88
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
After it will ask user_Name , and after entering username get following
Enter user-name: APPS
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Answer (score 0):

EBS admin/contact should provide the proper TNS entry and you should add it to your `tnsnames.ora`. If you are trying development for EBS I doubt you need a connection to "mymachine" which would be a non-standard name for a EBS instance.